# ExtJS Grid Filter fires too frequently

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an ExtJS 6.2 grid using the 'classic' API. I don't do a super-ton of Ext, so please bear with me.  But we have a grid we largely re-use over and over in various apps with slight customizations. In one, we have a text field for a filter.  But that filter triggers a reload REALLY fast as default behavior.  Too fast for someone to type in anything meaningful. I'd like to slow that puppy down.  Ideally, I'd like the reload to only happen when the menu is CLOSED, but if I can at least increase the time from someone to type and a reload, I can at least make it reasonable.

Problem is that I've no idea how to do that, and a brief perusal of the helps docs doesn't seem to show me any setting (maybe I'm looking in the wrong place).  Any ideas?

The filter is defined as:

{
type: 'string',
dataIndex: 'assetId',
value: '',
active: false
}

Comment: Please share your code showing how this filter is implemented, what triggers the reload. There are some options to achieve what you need but it is hard to help without the code.

Comment: I added the filter definition.  The full grid definition is kind of divided among component modules that get pieced together at the end and is hard to capture and show.  But the above is an example of the filter which is applied to one of the columns.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a buffer to the change event. That way as long as someone types no event will be handled. Once no one changes the textfield value for 500ms the event will be handled.

```
controller: 'main',

items: [{
    xtype: 'textfield',
    fieldLabel: 'Filter By Name',
    listeners: {
        change: 'onFilterfieldChange',
        buffer: 500
    }
}]
```

Controller

```
Ext.define('MyApp.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',
    alias: 'controller.main',

    onFilterfieldChange: function(textfield, newValue) {
        let store = this.getViewModel().getStore('gridStore');
        
        store.clearFilter(true);
        store.setFilter([
            { property: 'firstName', value: newValue}
        ]);
        store.load();
    }
});
```

Comment: That sounds really good.  What does fnInController need to look like to trigger that load?  right now, I don't need a custom method to fire the load it just sort of happens.